# Knowing checkbox state using javascript

Tags: javascript, input, checkbox

I have written the following code

```
function check()
{
    var text = document.getElementById('myCheckBox').checked?'check In':'check Out';
    alert(text) ;
}
```

My check box is the following

```
<input type = 'checkbox' id = 'myCheckBox' onChange= 'check();' />
```

My problem is that it always alert 'check In'..

But `alert(document.getElementById('myCheckBox').checked)` 
alerts true or false depending on the checkbox state as expected..

So what is the problem?

Comment: [Seems to work correctly](http://jsfiddle.net/EMwff/1/) Though you really should fix your HTML to remove the spaces around the attributes. `type='checkbox'`, not `type = 'checkbox'`, etc...

Comment: i agree with @Michael.. its work in fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jXZXr/2/

Answer (score 0):

I changedmy code to the following and it worked

```
function check()
 {
       var text = document.getElementById('myCheckBox').checked=='true'?'check In':'check Out';
       alert(text) ;
 }
```